# Can we use "highfalutin" to describe a person?

Tags: word-usage

Often, I've seen "highfalutin" used to describe words or speech.

But as for word usage, is it ok to use "highfalutin" to describe a self-important / pompous person?

E.g.: *This highfalutin guy is getting on my nerves...*

Comment: Does your dictionary not show the adjective form of [highfalutin](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/highfalutin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gnawme points out in his comment, some [dictionaries](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/highfalutin) make reference to **highfalutin** referring to people

> used for describing people, language, or ideas that sound very educated and difficult to understand

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=highfalutin&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,highfalutin;,c0) shows numerous references that use the term for people.

Comment: Btw, the ngram shows the *total* usage for that word right?

Comment: -1 Wait. That's already GR! Gnawme declared it so already.

Comment: @Kris As I said, Gnawme gave the cite. I think it is helpful to also give the definition. The ngram is intended to answered, I would have supplemented his with this info in a comment.

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, and a quick look makes it seems like more cites may be to things rather than people, but the latter is more than nominal.

Answer (score -1):

If "highfalutin" is an adjective, then it *technically* can describe anything, including people, so yes.

Comment: Of course you know I don't mean that...

Comment: I presume he wants to know about more than grammatical correctness — "The sunset looks quiet" is grammatically correct, but still nonsense in everyday speech.